# Como le hago que me muestre la información de mi select seleccionado al imprimir una parte de mi div

Tags: javascript, html5

Hola tengo un problema con mi código, y es que este tiene un botón de imprimir el cual solo imprime un area de mi pagina web (solo imprime el div de mi pagina web) dentro de mi div tengo un form el cual tiene varios select y el problema es que cuando le apretó al botón de imprimir este no me muestra la información que seleccione en mi form (donde están todos mis select), les agradecería mucho si me pudieran ayudar, me ayudarían mucho gracias.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      .container h2{
        text-align: center;
      }
      .container p{
        text-align: center;
      }
      .texto_total {
        align-items: center;
      }
      .botones_enviar {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .botones_borrar_imprimir {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }
      .boton_imprimir {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:800;
        font-size:14px;
        color:#ffffff;
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-bottom:10px;
        padding-left:30px;
        padding-right:30px;
        background-color:#E20F7E;
        border-color: #E20F7E;
      }
      .centrar {
      text-align: center;
      }
      select { width: 400px; text-align-last:center; }

      .logo-conaxfra {
        position: absolute;
        left: -50px;
        top: 60px;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div id="imp1">

    <a class="logo-conaxfra" href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/GRhtyHj/logo-peque-o3.png" alt="logo-peque-o3" border="0"></a>
    
    <center>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Cotización Libretas</h2>
          <p> Cotiza y envianos tu presupuesto.</p>
          <b>
          <hr>
          </b>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div> <br><br>

    <center>

    <form action="mailto:david_swag_v@hotmail.com" method="post" name="sumar" id ="contacto" enctype="text/plain">

        <b>
        <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1"> Opciónes de impresión </p>
        </b>

        <label>Tipo</label> <br>
        <select name="Tipo" class="Tipo">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="100">SIN suaje/pestaña (22.5 x 29.2 cm)</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <label>Cantidad</label> <br>
        <select name="Cantidad" class="Cantidad">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="20">25</option>
            <option value="40">50</option>
            <option value="80">100</option>
            <option value="120">200</option>
            <option value="160">300</option>
            <option value="300">500</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <label>Impresión</label> <br>
        <select name="Impresion" class="Impresion">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="50">4/0 (Color solo frente)</option>
            <option value="100">4/4 (Color frente y vuelta)</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <label>Tipo de papel</label> <br>
        <select name="Tipodepapel" class="Tipodepapel">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="200">Coché 300 g</option>
            <option value="300">Cartulina sulfatada 12 pts 1 cara</option>
        </select>
        <br><br><br>
        
        <b>
        <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1">  Terminados </p>
        </b>

        <label>Plastificado frente y vuelta</label> <br>
        <select name="Plastificadofrenteyvuelta" class="Plastificadofrenteyvuelta">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="150">Delgado brillante (BOPP)</option>
            <option value="300">Delgado mate (BOPP)</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        <label>Esquinas redondeadas (con datos de contacto hacia arriba)</label> <br>
        <select name="Esquinasredondeadas" class="Esquinasredondeadas">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="0">Ninguna</option>
            <option value="80">4</option>
        </select>
        <br> <br><br>

    <div class="texto_total">
        <b>
        <label>Total</label> <br>
        </b>
        <input class="centrar" type="text" name="total"> <br> <br>
    </div>

  </center>

  </div>
    
    <div class="botones_enviar">
        <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" class="email" placeholder="Dirección e-mail"> <br> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar Cotización</button> <br> <br>
    </div>

    <div class="botones_borrar_imprimir">
        <div class="clear"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-8"> 
                <input type="Reset" value="Borrar Datos">
        </div> <br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <button class="boton_imprimir" type="button" onclick="javascript:imprim1(imp1);">Imprimir Cotización</button>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    </form>

  </center>

    <script>
      function imprim1(imp1){
      var printContents = document.getElementById('imp1').innerHTML;
              w = window.open();
              w.document.write(printContents);
              w.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
              w.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10
          w.print();
          w.close();
              return true;}
    </script>
  
    <script>
        var numero3 = 0, numero1 = 0, numero2 = 0, numero4 = 0, numero5 = 0, numero6 = 0;
    caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;

    $(".Tipo").change(function() {
      numero1 = parseFloat(caja["Tipo"].value);
      mostrar();
    });
    
    $(".Cantidad").change(function() {
      numero2 = parseFloat(caja["Cantidad"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".Impresion").change(function() {
      numero3 = parseFloat(caja["Impresion"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".Tipodepapel").change(function() {
      numero4 = parseFloat(caja["Tipodepapel"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".Plastificadofrenteyvuelta").change(function() {
      numero5 = parseFloat(caja["Plastificadofrenteyvuelta"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".Esquinasredondeadas").change(function() {
      numero6 = parseFloat(caja["Esquinasredondeadas"].value);
      mostrar();
    });
    
    function mostrar() {
        if (numero1 >= 0 && numero2 >= 0 && numero3 >= 0 && numero4 >= 0 && numero5 >= 0 && numero6 >= 0) {
            var resultado = 0;
            resultado = (numero1 + numero2 + numero3 + numero4 + numero5 + numero6);
            caja["total"].value = (resultado);  
        }
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funcionó imprimiendo directamente desde el onClick() así:

```
<button class="boton_imprimir" type="button" onclick="window.print()">Imprimir Cotización</button>
```